# How use default constructor for complex numbers

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I have a more complicated application of complex numbers that I'm having trouble with.  I've looked at [simple complex ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035525/c-complex-numbers-what-is-the-right-format), and [usage 1](http://www.justskins.com/forums/basic-c-app-in-200539.html), and [usage 2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/complex/).  I'm having trouble applying that to my specific example, which has to be c++ 98 version.

I had luck doing this with a template class, but the later one is different:

```
 TYPE data_var(fvalue, fvalue);
```

But having trouble with a more complicated one:

```
case  <ourcomplex float>:
OurClassComplex* data_var( dat, dat);  //this does not compile
```

has error messages:

```
error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression,
warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect ,
error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char' to 'std::complex<float>*'
```

This used to be defined as follows, but we can't use this version anymore (must use 98 version):

```
((OurClassComplex*)(data_var))->real( dat);
((OurClassComplex*)(data_var))->imag( dat);
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working for c++ 98?  I can't share OurClassComplex info, so hopefully you get the gist from the example that worked.  It's complex!  ;)

Added:  Sorry I can't give all the class info. It's enormous and not something I can share.  Hopefully people can tell what I'm talking about with what I gave.  I'd appreciate not down-voting me, since I'm sharing what I can.

Comment: Any reason you are not using `std::complex`?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to declare a pointer with`OurClassComplex* data_var( dat, dat);`?

Comment: They re-wrote them all so they are like std::complex, but work for what we need.  Usually, I've found that when people do that, it's because of cross-platform needs, or project specific reasons.  It probably works just like std::complex.  My team mate pointed me to the links for std::complex, so it is very similar, I'm sure.

Comment: We have to use the initialization to declare this because it's c++ 98, not c++ 11 now.

Comment: We need this version:  complex (const T& re = T(), const T& im = T());

Comment: Like I said, this was originally c++ 11, and written as a pointer for what we need to do with it.  I'm converting  it to c++ 98.

Comment: if cross-platform is needed then obviously `std::complex` would be much more portable than your custom code

Comment: I wasn't the one who made the choice to do this.  There must be reasons.  It's too deep to share it all.

Comment: I wound up doing a reinterpret cast... *reinterpret_cast<OurClassComplex *>(data_var) = OurClassComplex(dat, dat);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
OurClassComplex* data_var( dat, dat);
```

You are initializing a pointer to a `OurClassComplex`.  A pointer has a single initializer which is the address of the thing it points to.  So when the compiler sees

```
OurClassComplex* data_var( dat, dat);
```

It treats the comma in the initializer as the comma operator and not a constructor call.  That means it is going to discard the first `dat` and try and use the second `dat` to initialize `data_var` with.

If you need a pointer then you need to use

```
OurClassComplex* data_var = new OurClassComplex( dat, dat);
```

Which will create a new instance dynamically.  You must remember to delete it when done though otherwise you will have a memory leak.

If you do not need a pointer then you just need

```
OurClassComplex data_var( dat, dat);
```

Which will create a object with automatic storage duration and you do not need to clean it up manually but instead it will be destroyed when the scope is left.

Comment: I did \*data_var = new OurClassComplex( dat, dat); , since it's in a case statement.  The error message changed to " error: invalid conversion from 'std::complex<float>*' to 'signed char'
".  Any ideas?  It's closer!  Thank you!

Comment: It removed the \* after float, and I can't add it now.

Comment: ((OurClassComplex\*)(data_var)) = new OurClassComplex( dat, dat); Is a little better.  Now it's just saying  warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future.  That might be it.

Comment: @Michele Try just `data_var = new OurClassComplex( dat, dat);`

Comment: It was an error message, above.  invalid conversion.  Must have to do with the template.  Windows build called that cast an error, and mac was a warning.  Uh oh.

Comment: @Michele Without a [mcve] and the actual error text that goes with it there is not much more I can do.

Comment: @Michele No problem.  Glad to help.